# If x and y are (signed) ints is ~x+~y+1 == ~(x+y); always true in C?

Tags: c, integer-arithmetic, binary-operators

I am reading Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective and in  Chapter 2, Homework Problem 2.81, the following assignment is presented:

"2.81 ◆
We are running programs on a machine where values of type int are 32 bits. They
are represented in two’s complement, and they are right shifted arithmetically.
Values of type unsigned are also 32 bits.

We generate arbitrary values x and y, and convert them to unsigned values as
follows:

```
/* Create some arbitrary values */
int x = random();
int y = random();
```

For each of the following C expressions, you are to indicate whether or
not the expression always yields 1. If it always yields 1, describe the underlying
mathematical principles. Otherwise, give an example of arguments that make it
yield 0."*

I am interested in clause C which stands:

C. ~x+~y+1 == ~(x+y)

I have tried compiling many examples (including edge cases with negative and positive overflow) with different values for x and y and have found that this usually holds. I understand this is not a proof and although my working hypothesis is that this holds I do not know why. My question is if this holds and if it does a lead on why would be very useful (explaining why is the task at hand).

*Bryant, Randal E; O'Hallaron, David R. (2013) Computer Systems: *A Progammer's Perspective*, Pearson.

Comment: Overflow on signed integers invokes undefined behaviour. But that seems to be not about signed, but apparently **unsigned** integers. Or why else did you add the information about `ux` etc?

Comment: @Olaf I just copied the original question. But the clause I mentioned makes no use of that part of the question, namely, ux and uy. It just uses x and y which are ints.

Comment: Learn using markdown! Do you mean _integers_ or `int`s? And why did you add the mentioned snippet about `unsigned`? If the values are signed, the code can invoke UB for certain values. Thus any result is correct, even  the comparison being true **and** false for the same input.

Comment: I mean `int`s. I just copied the original question. The specific clause I am interested makes no use of `ux` and `uy`. I will delete the `unsigned` part of the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: The text at "2.81 ◆" suggests that you're meant to ignore UB but it doesn't come right out and say it. Using "reasonable behaviour" (no nasal daemons) the equivalence still holds for signed ints, for the same reason that it holds for unsigned ints.